# Replacing fascia board: what kind of contractor?

Tags: roofing, gutters, contractors

I was cleaning my gutters yesterday and I noted that the fascia board is coming apart.

I don't have the time or skills to do it myself.  What kind of contractor would be best to hire?  The ones I can think of are a roofing outfit, a gutter outfit, and a handyman.

Answer (score 2):

I would actually recommend a handyman first.  There are gutters, carpentry, and painting involved and handyman should be adept at the disassembly required, the carpentry, and painting required.

A siding contractor might work as well, but they probably would not paint and may not want to mess with the gutter.

A gutter company would be my last choice as I suspect most would not consider such a repair in their scope.

I would NOT recommend a roofer due to the carpentry and painting.

Answer (score -1):

Most roofing contractors are licensed to perform roofing related carpentry, find a reputable and reliable one from personal references rather than advertisements and explain what you need. He/she will tell you whether or not they are capable.